# How to connect two memu emulators for socket connection in android?

Tags: sockets, android-emulator, portforwarding

I am new in android and trying to test my android app for socket connection between two emulators, one as server and second as client, as they can send and receive data. I created two projects for server socket and client socket with same package name in android studio 2.3.3 and want to run every project on separate emulator. I know to run this scenario I need to do port forwarding via telnet commands and know how to do it for default  android studio emulators, but I want to use it for memu emulators. I don’t know if memu supports telnet, the way to do port forwarding is exactly the same like android studio emulators and if not (memu doesn’t support telnet) is there solution for my goal and how to do it?
I set ADB host port for first emulator  (server socket) to 5559 , static ip 10.0.3.14 and for second emulator (client socket) to 5563, ip 10.0.3.15. When I run “telnet localhost 5558” to connect (memu) emulator console in cmd, result is this message: “Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5558: Connect failed”. But if I run “telnet localhost 5559” telnetlocalhost window appears! I really surprised because when run adb devices command it shoe 5558 port number (console port), but telnet work for 5559 port number (adb port).
I see in memu manager window, network settings,advanced there is a port forwarding button, but I don’t think it is the same I want. Also read on memu blog we can setup LAN with multiple MEmu instances via bridge connection, but I read another place “Network bridging does not work when the underlying physical network device is a wireless device”. So I confused if bridge connection can help me while I’m using laptop that (android)memu emulators run on it.
I really appreciated everyone can help me to find how connect two memu emulators for socket connection?

P.S: Finally, I apologize if I wrote more than enough and sorry for my poor English.